# Unable to copy a database on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have permissions for read and writing on AndroidManifest:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

... because I want to copy one file. I'm performing this process in two steps:

#### 1. Launching an Intent so the user creates the file where he wants:

This code is mostly the example of [the Android developers site](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files).

```java
    private void createFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/vnd.sqlite3");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "test.db");

        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
    }
```

#### 2. Copy the file.

The intent returns a [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri), so inside the `onActivityResult`:

```java
try {
    destinationOutputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(data.getData());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(where `data` is the Intent), I'm able to get the output stream.

Finally, and according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream)), I should be able to copy the file:

```java
try {
    Long totalBytes = Files.copy(originalPath, destinationOutputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(where `originalPath` is the path (of type Path) where the original file is stored).

But, on runtime, I'm getting the following error:

```lua
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Comment: What exactly is the exception?

Comment: @Sarah I build the app again and the error changed, maybe the previous error was from another implementation. Sorry :)

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607324/error-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread-since-it-may-potentially-lock-t